# Error when trying to login in admin page

Tags: magento2, admin

When I make the login at the admin page, it redirects me to a page with this written:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magenteiro/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 591

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magenteiro/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 591
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getArgonHash('root123', 'RpGe9HuhfMQxtBhP') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:279]
#2 Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->isValidHash('root123', '2995c3c04580a77e...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:266]
#3 Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->validateHash('root123', '2995c3c04580a77e...') called at [vendor/magento/module-user/Model/User.php:626]
#4 Magento\User\Model\User->verifyIdentity('root123') called at [generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:149]
#5 Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->verifyIdentity('root123') called at [vendor/magento/module-user/Model/User.php:598]
#6 Magento\User\Model\User->authenticate('root', 'root123') called at [generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:140]
#7 Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->authenticate('root', 'root123') called at [vendor/magento/module-user/Model/User.php:653]
#8 Magento\User\Model\User->login('root', 'root123') called at [generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:158]
#9 Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->login('root', 'root123') called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php:162]
#10 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('root', 'root123') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#11 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent('login', array('root', 'root123')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#12 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('root', 'root123') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#13 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', array('root', 'root123'), array(array('security_admin_s...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php:59]
#14 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('root', 'root123') called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:205]
#15 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:157]
#16 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:125]
#17 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000001a12184200000000360a945b#, &Closure#000000001a12184100000000360a945b#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#18 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#19 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#), array(array('adminLoadDesign'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:32]
#20 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#, &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000001a12184200000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000001a121a7c00000000360a945b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000001a121a4900000000360a945b#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

I already tried the `pecl install libsodium` command, removing the ";" from the sodium extension in php.ini, fresh install and creating another admin user. I'm using php 7.4, magento 2, xampp, apache2 and ubuntu. This is my first time trying to install the magento 2 because I'm still studying, so my project is a fresh install with the samples (did everything using composer).

Comment: Magento itseltf not recommending php7.4
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html
Also this my help you:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23511
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25025

Comment: oh ok, I think I'll gor for php 7.3 then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have installed the **sodium php extension**

This is common error in `Encryptor.php` file when you don't enable/install sodium extension.

Installation manual 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/sodium.installation.php

Refrence:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23511 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23405

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that, but, how do I install it?  The instructions are kinda unclear, didn't understand well...

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was unclear

Comment: You can try this: https://lukasmestan.com/install-libsodium-extension-in-php7/

Comment: when I try the "sudo echo "extension = sodium.so" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sodium.ini" it says that I don't have permission. I checked inside the mods-available folder the sodium.ini doesn't exist

Comment: you need to have root access to do this

Comment: I have it, I've inserted sudo before the command, the problem is: the file sodium.ini does not exists even after doing the "sudo pecl install -f libsodium" command

Comment: Try `locate sodium.ini` you will find actual location of this file

Comment: got this:
 /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sodium.ini
 /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/sodium.ini
but none for my php version (7.4)

Comment: The issue in this case was indeed with sodium so this answer should be accepted.  The problem is that sodium was loaded properly in CLI context but not in apache context. Reinstalling via PECL and adding extension="<path_to_sodium>" on the correct php.ini was enough to fix the issue. If you could add it to your answer for other users it would help to clarify that they should be seeing the sodium section in their phpinfo on the webserver context.